# tf.estimator.predict slow with tensorflow ranking module

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, ranking, tensorflow-estimator

I'm currently using the [TensorFlow Ranking module](https://github.com/tensorflow/ranking) for a recommendation task. Specifically I'm modifying [this tutorial file](https://github.com/tensorflow/ranking/blob/master/tensorflow_ranking/examples/tf_ranking_libsvm.py) for my own purpose. I can't say the tutorial was very friendly to new users. As this is the first time I've interacted with TensorFlow, I'm just trying to make it run.

As you may notice, [the example file](https://github.com/tensorflow/ranking/blob/master/tensorflow_ranking/examples/tf_ranking_libsvm.py) doesn't say how to make predictions, so after I finished training the model, I modified its [`train_and_eval()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/ranking/blob/master/tensorflow_ranking/examples/tf_ranking_libsvm.py#L370) function to predict. Here's my code.

```
def _train_op_fn(loss):
        """Defines train op used in ranking head."""
        update_ops = tf.compat.v1.get_collection(tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
        minimize_op = optimizer.minimize(
                loss = loss, global_step = tf.compat.v1.train.get_global_step())
        train_op = tf.group([minimize_op, update_ops])
        return train_op

ranking_head = tfr.head.create_ranking_head(
        loss_fn = tfr.losses.make_loss_fn(loss),
        eval_metric_fns = get_eval_metric_fns(),
        train_op_fn = _train_op_fn
)

estimator =tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=tfr.model.make_groupwise_ranking_fn(
                group_score_fn=make_score_fn(),
                group_size = group_size,
                transform_fn=make_transform_fn(),
                ranking_head=ranking_head),
        config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(
                output_dir, save_checkpoints_steps=1000))

def predict_(feature_dict = {}):
    if feature_dict == {}:
        feature_dict = input_fn()
    pred_fn, pred_hook = get_eval_inputs(feature_dict)
    generator_ = estimator.predict(input_fn = pred_fn, hooks = [pred_hook])
    pred_list = list(generator_)

    return pred_list
```

The `predict_` function takes dictionary

```
{'feature 1':[doc 1 score, doc 2 score...], 
 'feature 2':[doc 1 score, doc 2 score...], 
 ...}
```

and returns a list a scores for all docs in that order. (or at least that's what I think it should do)

The prediction results are very good. Problem is, it's really slow. Prediction for 400 docs takes more than 1 second (I only have 4 features). Is this a normal speed or there's space for optimization in the code? I heard `tf.estimator` reloads the graph everytime it makes a prediction, but I can't tell if it's the problem here.

Comment: are you running your model on CPU or GPU?

Comment: I didn't do anything regarding that. So I believe by default it runs on CPU. Is that a deciding factor?

Comment: if speed is a concern you should always run tf on a GPU it's ~20x faster

Comment: Thank you I'm trying out tensorflow-gpu. So did you mean my predict function looks fine? Nothing looks like it's causing redundant action from the machine, or could be optimized?

Comment: from the code you posted everything look fine

Comment: > "I heard tf.estimator reloads the graph everytime it makes a prediction, but I can't tell if it's the problem here." Yes, once per call to `estimator.predict`, are you calling `_predict ` once per example, or does pred_fn produce all your examples?

Comment: Thanks for this question and your post. I am trying to do what you are doing but are having issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62540588/cannot-convert-generator-to-list-from-estimator-predict because somehow I can't covert the generator to list. Any ideas on how to do that?